# How to build a hierarchical view of inherited classes in Python?

Tags: python, class, multiple-inheritance, metaclass

This is a question I tried to avoid several times, but I finally couldn't escape the subject on a recent project. I tried various solutions and decided to use one of them and would like to share it with you. Many solutions on internet simply don't work and I think it could help people not very *fluent* with classes and metaclasses.

I have hierarchy of classes, each with some class variables which I need to read when I instantiate objects. However, either these variables will be overwritten, or their name would be mangled if it has the form `__variable`. I can perfectly deal with the mangled variables, but I don't know, with an absolute certainty, which attribute I should look in the namespace of my object. Here are my definitions, including the class variables.

```
class BasicObject(object):
    __attrs = 'size, quality'
    ...

class BasicDBObject(BasicObject):
    __attrs = 'db, cursor'
    ...

class DbObject(BasicDBObject):
    __attrs = 'base'
    ...

class Splits(DbObject):
    __attrs = 'table'
    ...
```

I'd like to collect all values stored in `__attrs` of each class when Instantiate the `Splits` class. The method `__init__()` is only defined in the class `BasicObject` and nowhere else. Though, I need to scan `self.__dict__` for mangled `__attrs` attributes. Since other attributes have the pattern `attrs` in these objects, I can't filter out the dictionary for everything with the pattern `__attrs` in it ! Therefore, I need to collect the class hierarchy for my object, and search for the mangled attributes for all these classes.

Hence, I will use a `metaclass` to catch each class which calls `__new__()` method which is being executed when a `class` definition is encountered when loading a module. By defining my own `__new__()` method in the base class, I'll be able to catch classes when each class is instantiated (instantiation of the `class`, not an object instantiation).

Here is the code :

```
import collections

class BasicObject(object) :
    class __metaclass__(type) :
        __parents__ = collections.defaultdict(list)

        def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct) : 
            klass = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
            mro = klass.mro()
            for base in mro[1:-1] :
                cls.__parents__[name] = mro[1]

            return klass


    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs) :
        """
        Super class initializer.
        """

        this_name = self.__class__.__name__
        parents = self.__metaclass__.__parents__
        hierarchy = [self.__class__]
        while this_name in parents :
            try :
                father = parents[this_name]
                this_name = father.__name__
                hierarchy.append(father)
            except :
                break

        print(hierarchy)
        ...
```

I could have access attributes using the class definition, but all these classes are defined in three different modules and the main one (`init.py`) doesn't know anything about the other modules.

This code works well in Python 2.7 and should also work in Python 3.*. However, Python 3.* have some new features which may help write a simpler code for this kind of introspection, but I haven't had the time to investigate it in Python 3.0.

I hope this short explanation and example will save some of your (precious) time :-)

Comment: I think your _answer_ should go in the.. answers.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right ! But I don't know how to directly post an "answer" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the question is the answer; simply because I couldn't find anything other than the "Ask Question" button on the site. Did I miss something ?